# Linked list program facing segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I was writing a C++ program to implement a linked list. On compilation it's not giving any error but in the output windows it goes blank and program ended with

> list1.exe has 
>   encountered a problem and needs to close.

Debugger response: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Maybe it's because of memory leakage, but I'm not able to figure out the exact bug and how can we fix that. Please what's wrong in the prog and what should be fixed?

Below is the code

```
  //Program to implement linked list

  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>

  using namespace std;

  class Node
  {
      int data;
      Node * next;

   public:
      Node (){}
      int getdata(){return data ;}
      void setdata(int a){data=a;}
      void setnext(Node* c){next=c;}
      Node* getnext(){return next;}
  };

  class linkedlist
  {
      Node* head;

  public:
      linkedlist(){head=NULL;}
      void print ();
      void push_back(int data);
  };

  void linkedlist::push_back(int data)
  {
      Node* newnode= new Node();
      if(newnode!=NULL)
      {
          newnode->setdata(data);
          newnode->setnext(NULL);
      }
      Node* ptr= head;

      if(ptr==NULL) 
          {head=newnode;}
      while ((ptr->getnext())!=NULL)
      {
          ptr=ptr->getnext();
      }
      ptr->setnext(newnode);
  }

  void linkedlist::print()
  {
      Node* ptr=head;
      if(ptr==NULL)
          {cout<<"null"; return;}

      while(ptr!=NULL)
      {
          cout<<(ptr->getdata())<<" ";
          ptr=ptr->getnext();
      }
  }

  int main()
  {
     linkedlist list;
      list.push_back(30);
      list.push_back(35);
      list.print();
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please format your code readably!

Comment: at which line does it break ? or at least which method ?

Comment: Have you used a debugger? No? Why not?

Comment: hi luchian..i am sorry actually i am new in this..can you please tell how should i use a debugger..i am developing this in COdeblocks IDE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is here:

```
if(ptr==NULL) {head=newnode;}
while ((ptr->getnext())!=NULL)
{
    ptr=ptr->getnext();
}
ptr->setnext(newnode);
```

There's probably meant to be a `return;` in the `if (ptr == NULL)` part; as it stands, it sets `head = newnode`, but then continues to try to access `ptr->getnext()`, which causes the segfault.

Some answers have suggested setting `ptr = head = newnode`, but note that the bottom line is `ptr->setnext(newnode)`—this would cause `head->getnext() == head`. Infinite list!

For your interest, here's your code:

- Formatted nice;
- Cleaned up not to use `using namespace std;` (see the [C++ FAQ on this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/using-namespace-std.html));
- Takes advantage of [const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/overview-const.html);
- etc.

Enjoy!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(): next(NULL) {}

    int getdata() const {
        return data;
    }

    void setdata(int a) {
        data = a;
    }

    Node *getnext() const {
        return next;
    }

    void setnext(Node *c) {
        next = c;
    }
};

class linkedlist {
    Node* head;

public:
    linkedlist(): head(NULL) {} 

    void print() const {
        Node *ptr = head;

        if (ptr == NULL) {
            std::cout << "null";
            return;
        }

        while (ptr != NULL) {
            std::cout << ptr->getdata() << " ";
            ptr = ptr->getnext();
        }
    }

    void push_back(int data) {
        Node *newnode = new Node();

        if (newnode == NULL) {
            throw std::runtime_error("out of memory!");
        }

        newnode->setdata(data);

        Node *ptr = head;

        if (ptr == NULL) {
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }

        while ((ptr->getnext()) != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->getnext();
        }

        ptr->setnext(newnode);
    }
};

int main() {
    linkedlist list;
    list.push_back(30);
    list.push_back(35);
    list.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: Because you put a lot of efforts in your answer to a very poorly written question.

Comment: @len: thanks alot man!!! yes you were right! i forgot put a return statement..but i didn't change anything else..and prog is working fine..grt man!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the following line: `while ((ptr->getnext())!=NULL)` ptr is NULL

Comment: @Len: One more help please...if i want to use this prog in future also...like making a header file and then including that file in future progs..can you please write and tell steps i need to do to achieve this..would appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `push_back` code is incorrect, and I've seen some other parts of your code that can be improved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
      int data;
      Node * next;

   public:
      Node(int d = 0) : data(d), next(NULL) {}

      int getdata() { return data; }
      void setdata(int a) { data = a; }

      void setnext(Node* c) { next = c; }
      Node* getnext() { return next; }
};

class linkedlist
{
      Node* head;

   public:
      linkedlist() : head(NULL) {}
      void print ();
      void push_back(int data);
};

void linkedlist::push_back(int data)
{
   Node* newnode = new Node(data);

   if(head == NULL)
   {
      head = newnode;
   }
   else
   {
      Node* last = head;
      while(last->getnext() != NULL)
         last = last->getnext();
      last->setnext(newnode);
   }
}

void linkedlist::print()
{
   Node* ptr = head;
   if(!ptr)
   {
      cout << "null";
      return;
   }

   while(ptr != NULL)
   {
      cout << ptr->getdata() << " ";
      ptr=ptr->getnext();
   }
}

int main()
{
   linkedlist list;
   list.push_back(30);
   list.push_back(35);
   list.print();
   return 0;
}
```

There are still some points to be improved...

Comment: Have you tried this? As with @Razvan's answer, yours will cause an infinite loop when it ties `head->next` to itself.